# How do I get a C# connection to MySQL on AWS

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh

I'm trying to open a connection to a MySql database which is on AWS behind SSH but having major issues.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var sshServer = "11.111.11.11";
            var sshUserName = "shane";
            var sshPassword = "";
            var databaseServer = @"hello202006662000000666.abcdefghijk.ap - southeast - 2.rds.amazonaws.com";
            var databaseUserName = "shane";
            var databasePassword = "password";
            var SSHPrivateKeyFile = @"C:\Users\sshane\myprivatekey.ppk";
            var SSHPassPhrase = "sdkypfihsblkdcbsadl;kvgsiudgf";
            var databasename = "production";

            var (sshClient, localPort) = ConnectSsh(sshServer, sshUserName, sshPassword, SSHPrivateKeyFile, SSHPassPhrase, 22, databaseServer, 3306);

            using (sshClient)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sshClient);
                Console.WriteLine(localPort);

                MySqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    Server = "localhost",
                    Port = localPort,
                    Database = "production",
                    UserID = "shane",
                    Password = "Jopassword"
                };

                using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(connection.Ping());
                    connection.Open();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }


    public static (SshClient SshClient, uint Port) ConnectSsh(string sshHostName, string sshUserName, string sshPassword = null,
string sshKeyFile = null, string sshPassPhrase = null, int sshPort = 22, string databaseServer = "localhost", int databasePort = 3306)
    {
        // check arguments
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshHostName))
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(sshHostName)} must be specified.", nameof(sshHostName));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshHostName))
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(sshUserName)} must be specified.", nameof(sshUserName));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshPassword) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshKeyFile))
            throw new ArgumentException($"One of {nameof(sshPassword)} and {nameof(sshKeyFile)} must be specified.");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseServer))
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(databaseServer)} must be specified.", nameof(databaseServer));

        // define the authentication methods to use (in order)
        var authenticationMethods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshKeyFile))
        {
            authenticationMethods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(sshUserName,
                new PrivateKeyFile(sshKeyFile, string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshPassPhrase) ? null : sshPassPhrase)));
        }

        // connect to the SSH server
        var sshClient = new SshClient(new ConnectionInfo(sshHostName, sshPort, sshUserName, authenticationMethods.ToArray()));
        sshClient.Connect();

        // forward a local port to the database server and port, using the SSH server
        var forwardedPort = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", databaseServer, (uint)databasePort);
        sshClient.AddForwardedPort(forwardedPort);
        forwardedPort.Start();

        return (sshClient, forwardedPort.BoundPort);
    }
```

The error I'm getting is 'reading from the stream has failed'.

The SSH *seems* to be OK, but I can't establish a connection to the MySql db. Have been trying for a couple of days now, and I'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which line in the code throws the exception? Are you able to do SSH to the same server via other SSH clients such as Putty or Mac/Linux terminal?

Comment: If `var databaseServer = @"hello202006662000000666.abcdefghijk.ap - southeast - 2.rds.amazonaws.com";` is the real value you're using (and not just an example), this looks like a problem. The `databaseServer` variable should be a valid computer host name (that the SSH server will establish a tunnel to); this cannot contain spaces.

Comment: Hi Chetan, yes can connect to the SSH server via Putty no worries.

Comment: Hi @BradleyGrainger - I've tried pretty much every permutation I can think of - the AWS name, localhost, 127.0.0.1. The details / creds in the code snippet have been changed to protect the guilty, but I am at a loss.